# OCLint debug in Xcode

Tags: xcode, static-analysis, clang-static-analyzer, oclint

OCLint is integrated to Xcode project (as Agregate target). But I write/edit OCLint rules in the separate files (like simple text files) and then build new/modified rules from the command line. Therefore if I need to debug the rule I have to use output to the console. But it's very tiring and provides poor information.

Is it possible to open OCLint as a project in Xcode (like I open other projects in Xcode)? If possible, how can I use it? If not, what IDE is suitable for this on Mac OS?